# upload file in JSP - how to change a default path for the uploaded file

Tags: java, jsp, upload

I have two jps pages to handle an upload of the single file. 
Here is a code for selecting a file:

```
 org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils, java.util.*, 
 java.io.File, java.lang.Exception" %>
...
 <form name="uploadFile" method="POST" action="processUpload.jsp"     
 enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="myfile"><br />
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
 ....
```

//--------handle uploaded file---------------------

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=windows-1252"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.DiskFileUpload"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.File"%>


<%
    System.out.println("Content Type ="+request.getContentType());
    System.out.println("Cookies" + request.getCookies());

    DiskFileUpload fu = new DiskFileUpload();
    // If file size exceeds, a FileUploadException will be thrown
    fu.setSizeMax(1000000);

    List fileItems = fu.parseRequest(request);
    Iterator itr = fileItems.iterator();

    while(itr.hasNext()) {
      FileItem fi = (FileItem)itr.next();

      //Check if not form field so as to only handle the file inputs
      //else condition handles the submit button input
      if(!fi.isFormField()) {
        System.out.println("\nNAME: "+fi.getName());
        System.out.println("SIZE: "+fi.getSize());
        //System.out.println(fi.getOutputStream().toString());
        File fNew= new File(application.getRealPath("/"), fi.getName());

        System.out.println(fNew.getAbsolutePath());
        fi.write(fNew);
      }
      else {
        System.out.println("Field ="+fi.getFieldName());
      }
    }
 %>
```

This code put a file into my build\web folder. 
How to set a path to a different directory on the server (assuming the write permissions are set) ?
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code (adapted for the [user guide](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html)):

```
// Create a factory for disk-based file items
DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
factory.setRepository(dir);

// Create a new file upload handler
DiskFileUpload upload = new DiskFileUpload(factory);

// Parse the request
List /* FileItem */ items = upload.parseRequest(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

To set a file upload path:

```
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory"%>
DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
factory.setRepository(new File('/path/to/store/files'));
DiskFileUpload fu = new DiskFileUpload(factory);
```

Comment: Also, note that DiskFileUpload is deprecated and you should be using ServletFileUpload (or PortletFileUpload).

Answer (score 0):

Why simply not specify the path when creating the file? You could set the path as part of your application configuration (JNI), or as a system property when the web server starts (using the -Dpath=...), and reading it using System.getProperty("path"). You could even use an environment variable defined on your system and read that environment variable using the [System.getenv](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv(java.lang.String)) method.

Alternativaly, you could create just a temporary file using the File.getTempFile method. If you just need to save the file to do something with it and never use it again, that's a better option - nevertheless, you have to delete the file yourself after you use it.

Answer (score -1):

... try something like this:

```
File newFile = new File(request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/someUploadDirectoryOnServer/"), multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
```