# how to get and use its contents of a uploaded file in a java program in jsp?

Tags: jakarta-ee

I wrote a HTML code to upload a file in jsp.now i have to take this data and work with it using a java program in jsp.can you please provide me a sample code of how to achieve this.

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [upload file in JSP - how to change a default path for the uploaded file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233639/upload-file-in-jsp-how-to-change-a-default-path-for-the-uploaded-file)

Comment: sir i tried the first jsp code of uploading a file and  i got the output,tried the second jsp code.there i m getting an empty page and if i add these lines DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();factory.setRepository(dir); i get error. should i import any jar file for it ?

Comment: Download apache-upload and add .jar files under WEB-INF/lib folder. http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm note sure about your code.  Please follows these steps

1. Download the binary distribution of apache commons-fileupload and apache commons-io (FileUpload depends on Commons IO, so make sure you have the version mentioned on the dependencies page in your classpath before continuing.)
2. Extract both these distributions and copy `commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar` and `commons-io-2.0.1.jar`  under WEB-INF/lib folder.
3. In the Servlet, you need to import `javax.servlet`,`javax.servlet.http`, `import java.io`, `java.util,org.apache.commons.fileupload`,`org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet` and `org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk packages`.

Demo:

Create a servlet file under WEB-INF/classes folder

```
package com.me;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;


public class FileUploadServlet extends HttpServlet
{
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                     HttpServletResponse response) 
                         throws ServletException, IOException
   {
        boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
        java.io.PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();
        final String SUCCESS="/success.jsp";
        final String FAIL="/fail.jsp";
        if(isMultipart) 
         {
          try
           {

             FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
             ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
             List items = upload.parseRequest(request);
             pw.print("total : " + items.size());
             Iterator iter = items.iterator();
             while (iter.hasNext()) 
             {
                FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();
             pw.print("total : " + item);
                if(!item.isFormField()) 
                  {
                     String fileName = item.getName();
                     String destFilePath=getServletContext().getRealPath("/upload/" + fileName);
                     File uploadedFile = new File(destFilePath);
                     item.write(uploadedFile);
                   }
              }
             request.setAttribute("message","file has been uploaded successfully!");
           }catch(Exception ex)
           {

              ex.printStackTrace();
              request.setAttribute("message","Cannot upload : " + ex.getMessage());
              getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(FAIL).forward(request,response);
           }
           getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(SUCCESS).forward(request,response);
        }
   }
}
```

Configure/register the servlet in WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<web-app>
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>fileupload</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.me.FileUploadServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fileupload</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/fileupload</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Content of the view (upload.jsp).

NOTE: Set enctype attribute of  with "multipart/form-data"

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="fileupload">
  <input type="file" name="file"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Content of success.jsp and fail.jsp

```
${message}
```

Create a folder named `upload` at root of `context`.

**JSP version** (This is not a recommended way)

upload1.jsp

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" 

action="showfile.jsp">
  <input type="file" name="file"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

showfile.jsp

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.Iterator" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory" %>


<%

 boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
 String content="";

 if(isMultipart) 
     {
        FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        List items = upload.parseRequest(request);

        Iterator iter = items.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) 
         {
            FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();
            if(!item.isFormField()) 
              {
                 BufferedInputStream buff=new BufferedInputStream(item.getInputStream());
                 byte []bytes=new byte[buff.available()];
                 buff.read(bytes,0,bytes.length);
                 content=new String(bytes);
              }
          }
     }
%>

Content of File:
<pre>
 <%=content%>
</pre>
```

Comment: sir i have tried the codes that are posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233639/upload-file-in-jsp-how-to-change-a-default-path-for-the-uploaded-file here for the first code i get output that uploads a file.i added jars, and the mentioned imports in the second program but when this program is run it shows an exception stating org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Unable to compile class for JSP
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
string:///index2_jsp.java:11: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class servlet
location: package javax,etc.what this means?what i must do to get the contents

Comment: sir i am a beginner to jsp and i cant able to grasp these concepts.i wrote a jsp program to display the contents of a file using request.getParameter() as follows  <%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%File obj=new File(request.getParameter(resume));
FileInputStream obj1=new FileInputStream(obj);int c;
while((c=obj1.read())!=-1){out.print((char)c);}%> but it shows me an exception .what is wrong here sir ?

Comment: @sheba : you can't use request.getParameter(). Post your code-work so I can help you out.

Comment: and i dont have classes folder in my project and should i change the contents of web.xml as mentioned above ?

Comment: sir i have used an jsp program that enables user to upload a file.and i dont know how to get the contents of the uploaded file using another jsp program.can you please tel me what are the steps i have to do to get the contents of the file uploaded.